# Saving a large ReadableStream to disk?

Tags: javascript, stream

I have a `ReadableStream` that potentially contains several gigabytes of data. As such, it is impractical to buffer it all into memory before saving it as a file.

Is it possible to instruct the *web browser* to save a `ReadableStream` as a file to disk? Or get a blob url from it?

(Incidentally, I am downloading and decrypting a file using [OpenPGP.js](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs))